# pull to refresh & infinite collection loading with mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

I have a view that looks like some kind of facebook stream with card items.

My current query is just getting the latest 20 items from the collection.

Problem 1:

I would like to update my cards with a pull to refresh. How can I update my collection that I get the latest documents without "redownloading" my last 20 documents?

e.g.

- I have 20 documents in the minimongo (client)
- now the server have 25 documents
- I do the pull to refresh on the client side
- I have 25 documents in the minimongo

How can I query this with mongoDB?

Problem 2:

I also have a infinite loader. so when I have reached the last card it fires a function.

How can I query this with mongoDB to get the next documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

You should pass a timestamp to the publication as a reactive var and when you pull-to-refresh, you update the timestamp. In the publication, you search for documents that have a createdAt date that is `$lte` the supplied timestamp.

Problem 2:

Also pass a limit option to the publication as a reactive var and when the infinite scroll is triggered you just increase the limit.